# Reading from file to struct into terminal, segmentation fault

Tags: c

I'm trying to read from a text file with similar lines (about 200 of them with some empty lines now and then).
I know that something can be uninitialized, but I'm blank as to what it is. What I'm trying to do right now is just read from a file and print it into the terminal window.

I really hope you can help me!
Thank you.

Example of a few lines of text file:

```
Fre     19/07 18.30     AGF - FCM      0 - 2     9.364   
Lor     20/07 17.00     VFF - RFC      2 - 2     4.771   
Son     21/07 14.00     OB - SDR       1 - 1     7.114
```

My struct looks like this:

```
struct match {
    char weekday[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    int day;
    int month;
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    char home_team[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    char away_team[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    int home_team_goals;
    int away_team_goals;
    int spectators_thds;
    int spectators_hdrs;
};
```

My `read_file` function looks like this:

```
void read_file(struct match *match) {
    FILE *fp;
    int i;
    fp = fopen("superliga-2013-2014", "r"); 
    while (!fp) {
        error("Cannot open file.");
    }

    struct match *matches = (struct match *) malloc(sizeof(match) * MAX_MATCHES);
    while(!feof(fp)) {
        fscanf(fp, " %s %i/%i %i.%i %s - %s %i - %i %i.%i \n", 
               matches[i].weekday, &matches[i].day, &matches[i].month, &matches[i].hours,
               &matches[i].minutes, matches[i].home_team, matches[i].away_team,
               &matches[i].home_team_goals, &matches[i].away_team_goals,
               &matches[i].spectators_thds, &matches[i].spectators_hdrs);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    free(fp);
}
```

And my `main` function looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    struct match *matches;
    void read_file(struct match *matches);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_MATCHES; ++i) {
        printf(" %s %i/%i %i.%i %s - %s %i - %i %i.%i ",
               matches[i].weekday, matches[i].day, matches[i].month, matches[i].hours,
               matches[i].minutes, matches[i].home_team, matches[i].away_team,
               matches[i].home_team_goals, matches[i].away_team_goals,
               matches[i].spectators_thds, matches[i].spectators_hdrs);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles with no problems, but I get a `Segmentation fault` when I try to run it. I then use Valgrind, and it gives me this message:

```
==12799== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==12799==    at 0x4007B8: main (in /home/dradee/Dropbox/UNI/Programmering/C/readfile)
==12799== 
==12799== Invalid read of size 4
==12799==    at 0x4007B8: main (in /home/dradee/Dropbox/UNI/Programmering/C/readfile)
==12799==  Address 0x34 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==12799== 
==12799== 
==12799== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==12799==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x34
==12799==    at 0x4007B8: main (in /home/dradee/Dropbox/UNI/Programmering/C/readfile)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Comment: Are you sure MAX_MATCHES is big enough for your file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) cast `malloc()`

   ```
   struct match *matches = (struct match *) malloc(sizeof(match) * MAX_MATCHES);
   ```

   is better as

   ```
   struct match *matches = malloc(sizeof(struct match) * MAX_MATCHES);
   ```
2. Check the result of `malloc()`, it returns `NULL` on failure.
3. Don't check `!feof()` because it's [always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong), so change this

   ```
   while(!feof(fp))
   ```

   with

   ```
   while (fscanf(fp, " %s %i/%i %i.%i %s - %s %i - %i %i.%i \n", 
          matches[i].weekday, &matches[i].day, &matches[i].month, &matches[i].hours,
          &matches[i].minutes, matches[i].home_team, matches[i].away_team,
          &matches[i].home_team_goals, &matches[i].away_team_goals,
          &matches[i].spectators_thds, &matches[i].spectators_hdrs) == 11)
   ```
4. And this is the most **important**: you iterate until `MAX_MATCHES` in the `printf()` loop, when you don't necessarily have read `MAX_MATCHES`. So you need to keep a count of the successfuly read items, and use that in the second `for` loop.

   You can for example return the count of read items from `read_file` to main, and use it.

   You already have a counter in `read_file()` but read the next point.
5. You never increment `i` in the `while` loop in `read_file()`.
6. This is very weired

   ```
   void read_file(struct match *matches);
   ```

   do you mean

   ```
   read_file(matches);
   ```
7. This is incorrect

   ```
   free(fp);
   ```

   you already did `fclose(fp)` which is the correct way to release a `FILE *`'s resources, the `free()` there will cause undefined behavior, which could be a segmentation fault, or any thing else, since it's undefined.
8. This makes no sense

   ```
   while (!fp) { ... }
   ```

   you meant

   ```
   if (!fp) { ... }
   ```
9. Your `read_file()` function only localy allocates the `structs` and then you have no access to them from `main()`, what you can do is this

   ```
   int read_file(struct match **matches)
   {
       FILE         *fp;
       int           i;
       struct match *match;        
       if (matches == NULL)
           return 0;
       *matches = NULL;
       fp       = fopen("superliga-2013-2014", "r");
       if (!fp)
       {
           error("Cannot open file.");
           return 0;
       }        
       match = malloc(sizeof(struct match) * MAX_MATCHES);
       if (match == NULL)
           return 0;
       while ((fscanf(fp, " %s %i/%i %i.%i %s - %s %i - %i %i.%i \n",
                  match[i].weekday, &match[i].day, &match[i].month, &match[i].hours,
                  &match[i].minutes, match[i].home_team, match[i].away_team,
                  &match[i].home_team_goals, &match[i].away_team_goals,
                  &match[i].spectators_thds, &match[i].spectators_hdrs) == 11) && (i < MAX_MATCHES))
       {
           i++;
       }
       fclose(fp);

       *matches = match;
       return i;
   }
   ```

   and then your `main()`

   ```
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
   {
       int           i;
       struct match *matches;
       int           count;
       count = read_file(&matches);
       for (i = 0 ; i < MAX_count ; ++i) 
       {
           printf(" %s %i/%i %i.%i %s - %s %i - %i %i.%i ",
                  matches[i].weekday, matches[i].day, matches[i].month, matches[i].hours,
                  matches[i].minutes, matches[i].home_team, matches[i].away_team,
                  matches[i].home_team_goals, matches[i].away_team_goals,
                  matches[i].spectators_thds, matches[i].spectators_hdrs);
       }
       free(matches);        
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I didn't expect such a thorough answer, and I'm grateful for that! If I could upvote you I would, but I don't have 9 reputation yet.
Thank you!